# Populate values of radio button from database using PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I'm trying to display values of a radio button which are fetched from the database. I want to use it to update a subject in a blog i am developing so if an admin chooses to change its visibility. 
What i need now is to be able to show the visibility of the subject so that it could be changed. 
I am expecting this code to work but it didn't:

```
<p>Visible:
              <input type="radio" name="visible" value="0"<?php if($sel_subject['visible'] == 0) { echo " checked"; } ?>
              /> No
              &nbsp;
              <input type="radio" name="visible" value="1"<?php if($sel_subject['visible'] == 1) { echo " checked"; } ?>
              /> Yes
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in short

```
<input type="radio" name="visible" value="0" <?=($sel_subject['visible'] == 0)?'checked':''?>/> No

<input type="radio" name="visible" value="0" <?=($sel_subject['visible'] == 1)?'checked':''?>/> Yes
```

Comment: Thank you! I just realised where my mistake is. I named a variable after I have another function that contains same variable. That's why it couldn't work.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php $sel_subject['visible'] = 0; ?>
<input type="radio" name="visible" value="0"<?php if($sel_subject['visible'] === 0) { echo " checked"; } ?>/> No
<input type="radio" name="visible" value="1"<?php if($sel_subject['visible'] == 1) { echo " checked"; } ?>/> Yes

<?php $sel_subject['visible'] = 1; ?>
<input type="radio" name="visible" value="0"<?php if($sel_subject['visible'] === 0) { echo " checked"; } ?>/> No
<input type="radio" name="visible" value="1"<?php if($sel_subject['visible'] == 1) { echo " checked"; } ?>/> Yes
```

**[Working Demo](http://codepad.org/q2rnGvrG)**